# input string 1 is invalid UTF-8

Tags: r, shiny

Don't beat hard, I only study R for 7 days and need help or advice (in quotation marks in Ukrainian):
Here are the links to the files (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kYWHfQJIVlLHzSK8xYow7MMV87rcjuwW)
You need to calculate the number "ЗА", "НЕ ГОЛОСУВАВ" and more. In the table without changing the data.
Here are the links to the files:

In a separate code it works fine.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(plyr)
library(boot)
library(dplyr)

aa1<-read.csv("g:/myapp/census-app/data/fin_gol.csv")
aa2<-as.data.frame(aa1)
aa<-aa2


validUTF8(aa$DPList.DPGolos)
ff1<-nrow(aa [aa$DPList.DPName == input$var1 & aa$DPList.DPGolos == "ЗА"])
```

Error in shiny:

```
Error in sourceUTF8 (fullpath, envir = new.env (parent = globalenv ())):
```

Here is the shiny code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
#aa<-11
#aa<-img(src="g:/myapp/www/Baluk.png")
aa1<-read.csv("g:/myapp/census-app/data/fin_gol.csv")
aa2<-as.data.frame(aa1)
aa<-aa2
bb<-22
cc<-33
dd<-44

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("WINDOW"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("var1", h4("SELECT BOX1"),
                  choices=list("Choice 1"=aa$DPList.DPName), selected = 1)


        ),
    mainPanel(
    textOutput("selected_var1")
  )



  )



)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output)
{

  output$selected_var1<-renderText ({
    ff1<-nrow(filter(aa, aa$DPList.DPName == input$var1 & aa$DPList.DPGolos == "ЗА"))
    #ff2<-(ff1$GL_Text)
    #ff<-data.frame(ff2)
    #View(ff1)
    paste("  ", ff1)
  })

}
#DPList.DPGolos
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Where is `validUTF8` implemented in shiny?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik,
Added a ribbon to the code:

    'Sys.setlocale (category = "LC_CTYPE", locale = "ukr")'

The error is missing, but it "ЗА" does not find it at all.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded. Started the code today - and everything worked !!